# How to check for matches where fields are different?

Tags: excel, compare, match, vlookup

I have 2 Excel spreadsheets and need to try to find matches based on product name but one file has something like Tylenol for example (only the product name) but the other file has Tylenol 100mg 100s. I want to see if the product name from my first file (just Tylenol) is on my 2nd file for the name Tylenol but ignore the 100mg 100s for example.

Is there a vlookup using a wilcard for my 2nd file or some other kind of match function? If someone could list out some code functions that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Didn't try anything as I'm not versed on matching when one field name has less than the other.

Comment: For a begins-with-criteria, you could e.g. use `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,SEARCH(A2,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,0)))`.

Comment: I tried the following on a record I know have product name matches between both files and it came out False however. =ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,SEARCH(B748,[Book2]Sheet1!$E$2:$E$180,0)))

Comment: For example, I have the following in one book: TIBSOVO 250MG TABLETS 60/BTL ASD
 and have Tibsovo on the file with just names. That should be a match if I can ignore the 250mg etc. I'm using the formula on the book that has the extended product description as I need to see if any products from book2 are in the file with the extended descriptions.

Comment: Replace `Book2` with the name of your 2nd workbook (e.g. `MySecond.xlsx`), it surely isn't `Book2`. Maybe best select the range `E2:E180` in it after deleting `[Book2]Sheet1!$E$2:$E$180` while your in the formula bar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually it is Book2 at the moment but just saved it as something else. So the formula now is: =ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,SEARCH(B748,[Blocks.xlsx]Sheet1!E$2:E$180,0))) but still getting a False on one that should match.